# SoapUI: Pass property values to called test case

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am a beginner in soapui testing. Hopefully you can help me solving this problem.

In my test project I have a test suites which contains several test cases. Multiple test case will start the same test case. To run this test case I need some property values to be transferred to this test case.

I tried to achieve this in two ways. But I failed in both.

1. I tried to call the test case and set the needed properties in the test case. I start the test case from a Groovy script. But I couldn't find a good example how to set the properties in the called test case.
2. I tried to get the property values of the calling parent test case inside the called test case. It looks like the parent test case that called the test case isn't available in the context of the running test case.

The test cases, that will call the same test case, will be run in parallel. So, I think it isn't a solution to first set the property values and then start the test case, because they will be overwritten by the other test cases that run at the same time. Also using test suite properties for these values won’t work because of running the test cases in parallel.

My test project looks like this.

```
MyProject
    TestSuite_APLtests
      TestCase_user_01
      Properties test step
      Run_test <groovy script>
      Step_01
      …..
    TestCase_user_02
      Properties test step
      Run_test <groovy script>
      Step_01
      …..
    TestCase_General
      Properties test step
      POST sessions
      Step_01
      …..
```

The ‘Properties test step’ of each ‘TestCase_user_’ contains a user and password needed in test case ‘TestCase_General’ and will be different for each test case.
In the ‘Run_test’ groovy script of each ‘TestCase_user_’ the test case ‘TestCase_General’ is started by using:

```
def myTestSuite = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("TestSuite_APLtests")
def myTestCase = myTestSuite.getTestCaseByName("TestCase_General")
myTestCase.run(null, false)
```

How can I add the properties user and password to the run comment that starts the test case?

If I try to get the property values with a groovy script in test case ‘TestCase_General’ I don’t know how to determine which test case has called ‘TestCase_General’. I found some posts on internet that suggests to use: `context.getProperty("#CallingRunTestCaseStep#")` to determine the calling test case. But this value is null. And when I try to check if the calling test case is available in the context by using: `context.hasProperty("#CallingRunTestCaseStep#")` this is false, so this doesn't work to find the calling test case.

Can someone tell me what the solution will be to get this working.

Thanks,

Comment: Only to clarify... do you want to know how to set the properties of your testCase before run it inside your groovy script?

Comment: I set the values of the properties ‘user’ and ‘password’ in the properties test step of each test case. In the Groovy script in these test cases I call the test case ‘TestCase_General’. The values of the properties ‘user’ and ‘password’ need to be passed to properties in test case ‘TestCase_General’ at the moment that I start that test case. I don’t know how to pass the properties from the calling test case to the called test case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set Test Case properties from groovy script with `setPropertyValue(name,value)` method, however if you run the Test Cases in parallel, this properties as you said will be overwritten for each Test Case calling `TestCase_General`. So instead of use `setPropertyValue` you can pass the `context` properties through the `run(StringToObjectMap properties, boolean async)` method in the [`WsdlTestCase.java`](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/testcase/WsdlTestCase.html) class. Your groovy code to call `TestCase_General` could be:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap

// get test suite
def myTestSuite = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("TestSuite_APLtests")
// get your test case
def myTestCase = myTestSuite.getTestCaseByName("TestCase_General")
// set the user and password properties in the context
context.setProperty("user","userTestCaseN")
context.setProperty("password","passwordTestCaseN")
// run the testCase passing the context
def contextMap = new StringToObjectMap( context )
myTestCase.run(contextMap,false);
```

To access the `context` properties in the groovy script of your `TestCase_General` use this code:

```
context.getProperty("userPassword")
```

Or if you prefer to use `context.expand`:

```
context.expand('${#user}')
```

Note that the use of `#` depends on how you are accessing the properties.

If you also need to use the `context` properties in the SOAP Test Request of your `TestCase_General` use this way `${#propetryName}` i.e:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <Header/>
   <Body>
    <request>
        <user>${#user}</user>
    </request>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you. I can try it in that way. But I’m afraid it won’t work if I run the test cases in parallel. If I set the property values in the test case before running the test will these be overwritten by another test case? For example test case 1 and test case 2 run at the same time. They use different user and password and start TestCase_General. I think than the values will be changed by one of these test cases after the value is set by the other test case. Or am I wrong and won’t this happen? I will try it, if it will work in this way. But maybe someone knows a good other solution for this.

Comment: Hi @Deddur, sorry at first I don't realize that you want to execute your tests in parallel, as you say the properties will be overwritten for each TestCase which call the TestCase_General. In order to run correctly in parallel you must use the context properties as you suggest in your question. I update my answer to fit this requirements. Try it `:)`.

Comment: Hi @albciff thank you for your explanation. I was away for some days, so it took some time before I could try your advice. I had already found out on the internet that I had to use the context for parsing the properties. But in these explanations I missed that I had first to set the properties in the context. I made the wrong assumption that properties used in a test case already are part of the context.
In the way you explained it works perfect (Y).